# Is it possible to get higher-level information from DeviceMotionEvent?

Tags: javascript, physics

total noobie on the topic, and not very good in physics, so have mercy.

I'm looking to use DeviceMotionEvent's acceleration and rotationRate info to control events appearing on the phone's screen in a browser environment.

For example: make the screen go red when the phone is suddenly stopped (decelerated).

How would I use the acceleration data to do that? are there libraries that simplify the job of de-fluttering the data and firing events base on thresholds (like the one above)?

I've googled around but there seems not to be much on the topic.

Comment: I only found one: https://github.com/adtile/Full-Tilt This might not be for everybody